# Bash - Pattern Match - Don't replace in script

Tags: bash

I have a pattern to replace in a bash script, and it replaces correctly if I run directly in terminal. But if I put the exact same code in a script it doesn't work.

Example:

```
test="1[[ 23 ]]4" && echo "${test//[[][[]*( )23*( )[]][]]/56}"
```

The above command outputs `1564` if I run in terminal, but it outputs `1[[ 23 ]]4` if I run in a script (I just create an empty script, put a bash shebang, paste the above code, add execute permission and run; I tried running with `./test.sh` and also with `bash ./test.sh` to make sure bash is the shell used, but still the same result).

It works if I change the code to:

```
test="1[[ 23 ]]4" && echo "${test//[[][[] 23 []][]]/56}"
```

but I want 0 or more spaces, so the 1st would be the correct choice, but for some reason it's not working in a script.

I think it might be related to glob expansion working differently in the terminal and in a script, but I don't know how to proceed. I read the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html), but still no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn on bash's extended globbing in the script (I think it's turned on automatically in interactive sessions, or maybe in your `~/.profile`) in order for `*()` constructs to work right:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s extglob
test="1[[ 23 ]]4" && echo "${test//[[][[]*( )23*( )[]][]]/56}"
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! The funny thing is that I suspected it was about glob expansion and tried both `shopt -s nullglob` (I think this would cancel all glob expansion) and `shopt -s globstar`, but haven't tried `shopt -s extglob`.